# Encrypted data types in RAML

Tags: encryption, raml

Am trying to define an API spec, that is expecting the post body to be signed and encrypted. Is there any way we can define this in RAML? Security schemes etc allow you to define authN/authZ etc but not sure how to indicate that the data itself needs to be signed and encrypted a certain way.

Comment: I'm not familiar with RAML, but encrypted data itself is randomized, and generally so are signatures. You can of course validate any structure that contains it (e.g. XMLdigsig / CMS, whatnot) but generally those are checked at runtime (I'm presuming here that you want to have an "encrypted" type checked at compile time, but I could be misunderstanding your question).